# Use curl instead of browser to get auth_token

Tags: box-api

Looking at: http://developers.box.com/get-started/#authenticating on step #2 I'm trying to use curl to enter the credentials (user/email/password) to get the auth_token. I'd rather do it this way instead of directing the user to their browser because I'm making a script for syncing.

Anyone have an idea how I can do this? can I just do a POST with curl? I'm using v2 of the API.

Answer (score 0):

You must send the user through the web page, unfortunately. However, since you are writing a script, you should also be aware that auth_tokens under the current system, so you can manually retrieve one and include it in your script.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess that's the short answer! I know how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing to note.   If you don't use the standard authentication flow that goes through the Box web ui, then Box's large customers that have all their users sign-on with SSO (Active Directory and similar) logins, won't be your customers.

So, basically, if you want your app to be picked up by enterprise-level customers, then follow the building guidelines that Box provides.

Comment: I'm not planning on large scale enterprise users.